# Select2 don't active when open with facebox jquery

Tags: php, jquery, css, jquery-select2, facebox

This is button call php file use facebox:

```
<a rel="facebox" href="demosearch.php"><Button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" style="float:right; width:150px; height:35px;" /><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-large"></i> Nhập sản phẩm</button></a>
```

And this is code php page use select2 jquery

```
<html>
<?php
    require_once('auth.php');
?>
<head>
 <!-- Thêm các tệp CSS và JavaScript của Select2 -->
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="saveproduct.php" method="post">
<center><h4><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-large"></i> Thêm mới hàng hóa</h4></center>
<hr>
<div id="ac">
<span>Mã hàng: </span><select name="product" class="my-select" required>
  <option></option>
  <?php
    include('../connect.php');
    $re = $db->prepare("SELECT pro_id, pro_name, pro_cat, pro_supplier FROM products_code");
    $re->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $re->fetch(); $i++) {
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['pro_id'];?> - <?php echo $row['pro_name']; ?> - <?php echo $row['pro_cat']; ?> - <?php echo $row['pro_supplier']; ?>"><?php echo $row['pro_id']; ?> - <?php echo $row['pro_name']; ?> - <?php echo $row['pro_cat']; ?> - <?php echo $row['pro_supplier']; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
<br>
</div>

<!-- Kích hoạt Select2 cho tag select của bạn -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Kích hoạt Select2 cho tag select của bạn
  $('.my-select').select2({
    placeholder: 'Chọn sản phẩm',
    minimumResultsForSearch: 1 
  });

  // Kích hoạt lại Select2 sau khi Facebox được mở
  $(document).bind('afterReveal.facebox', function() {
    $('.my-select').select2({
      placeholder: 'Chọn sản phẩm',
      minimumResultsForSearch: 1 
    });
  });

  // Hủy bỏ Select2 trước khi đóng Facebox
  $(document).bind('afterClose.facebox', function() {
    $('.my-select').select2('destroy');
  });
});
</script>

</form>
</body>

<?php include('footer.php');?>
</html>
```

If I remove rel="facebox" and open as a page then search in select2 actived. If I don't remove rel="facebox" then search in select2 no actived.
Pls help me!